# symfony setData() error

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm trying to put a value in form created by formbuilder, i took the value from another twig file by the request, and i'm trying to use $form->setData(array('field'=>value));

Code controller:

```
public function ModifierGestionMatchAction(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $idmatch = $request->get('idm');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $type = $em->getRepository("MainBundle:ReservationGestionStock")
        ->find($id);
    $match = $em->getRepository("MainBundle:Match")
        ->findOneByid($idmatch);
    $form = $this->createForm(ReservationGestionStockType::class, $type);
    $form->setData(array('hotel'=>null));
    $form->setData(array('match'=>$match));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid()){
        $em->persist($type);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute("ReservationGestionStockAfficher");
    }

    return $this->render('MainBundle:GestionStock:GestionStockModifierMatch.html.twig',
        array(
            "form" => $form->createView(),
            "match" => $match
        ));
}
```

my form code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('hotel',HiddenType::class)
        ->add('match',HiddenType::class)
        ->add('nb')
        ->add('nbr')
        ->add('Valider', SubmitType::class)
        ->add('Reset', ResetType::class);
}
```

Notice: the hotel and match are 2 entitys, i'm having problem with setData() for match, i tried to setdata of idmatch but its the same problem," the form isnt valid "

Comment: Your form builder is not set up to handle entities in those fields. You would need to alter your form builder using an [`EntityType field`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html), or provide it with `$match->getId()` instead, however if your `MainBundle:ReservationGestionStock::setMatch` expects an entity as well, the `$match->getId()` will not work, since Symfony forms use your model setters when issuing `handleRequest`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i did this and its working, but i think it's so weird ... anyway thanks everyone for replying me.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $gestion= new ReservationGestionStock();
        $gestion->setMatch(null);
        $gestion->setNb($form->getData()->getNb('nb'));
        $gestion->setNbr($form->getData()->getNbr('nbr'));
        $gestion->setHotel($hotel);
        $em->persist($hotel);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute("ReservationGestionStockAfficher");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$form->get('hotel')->setData('John');
$form->get('match')->setData($match);
```

Answer (score 0):

After submission just do that,
`$type = $form->getData(); $type->setHotel($hotel); $type->setMatch($match); then persist and flush $type`